# "An error occurred while communicating with the server. Reload" error in new Google Groups

Tags: google-groups

When accessing Google Groups I get the following error:

> An error occurred while communicating with the server. Reload

The error happens only when I'm logged in and when the *new* interface is turned on.

I couldn't find information on how to fix it.

Comment: Is this still an issue, or has this bug been quashed?